# What happens to Master-Detail after deleting (Managed Package)

Tags: managed-package, lookup, master-detail, delete, delete-managed-package

When I delete a Master-Detail relationship in my managed Package

1. Will it be replaced by a **Lookup**, like this [Knowledge arcticle](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005049) says?
2. Will there still be a **Master-Detail** relationship in our customers org, after upgrading, So it has to be deleted by admins?
   like this [ISVforce Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm) tells us.
3. Will it be **totally removed** everywhere? As according to this [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Ji9lAAC) there can be no MD-relationships on managed objects in foreign orgs.
4. Something else?

Answer (score 1):

The Master-Detail relationship (like any managed custom field) will **not** be deleted in the customer (subscriber) organisations, like stated in the ISV guide (2).

Instead it will be listed as 'unused component' under the package components settings **after** the upgrade to the new package version (without the Master-Detail relationship) was applied.

At this point an admin of an **specific** subscriber organisation is able to delete the Master-Detail relationship (assumed the relationship is not used by other components/integrations). The deletion now is like for an unmanaged Master-Detail relationship with all the consequences described in the knowledge article (1).